# How to create a jquery flipswitch that changes the page css on click

Tags: jquery

EDIT

I have a jquery flipswitch as such

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/day.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <title>Settings Page</title>

    <body>
<select name="flip-1"  id="flip-1" data-role="slider" data-theme="a">
  <option value="off"  >Off</option>
  <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

I want to create a function that allows the user to switch to an alternate stylesheet called night.css. I am aware that the onClick function does not work here. How do I go about creating a function that allows the user to switch to an alternate CSS when i slide/click on the flipswitch?

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.onchange()` here. You can use something like this:

**jQuery**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#flip-1").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "on")
      $("#mystyle").attr("href", "night.css");
    else
      $("#mystyle").attr("href", "day.css");
  });
});
```

**JavaScript**

```js
document.getElementById("flip-1").onclick = function () {
  var myStyle = document.getElementById("mystyle");
  if (this.value == "on")
    myStyle.setAttribute("href", "night.css");
  else
    myStyle.setAttribute("href", "day.css");
};
```

**HTML**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="mystyle" href="night.css" />
<select name="flip-1"  id="flip-1" data-role="slider" data-theme="a">
  <option value="off"  >Off</option>
  <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put an id to your css link for easier access

   ```
   <link href="day.css" id="switcher" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
   ```
2. Make the onchange function

   ```
   $('#flip-1').on('change', function() {
       if($(this).val() == 'on') {
           $("#switcher").attr('href', 'night.css');
       }
       else {
           $("#switcher").attr('href', 'day.css');
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple `onChange` event handler which overwrites the `link` element in your DOM.

For example:

```
$('#flip-1').change(function(){
    var linkElement = $('head').find('link[rel=stylesheet]');
    if(linkElement.attr('href') == 'style1.css') {
        linkElement.attr('href', 'style2.css');
    } else {
        linkElement.attr('href', 'style1.css');
    }
});
```

The `'link[rel=stylesheet]'` selector means "find link elements in head, which have the rel equal to stylesheet"..

*Note: This assumes that you have only one CSS binding link element present in your `head`, otherwise assign an ID to the `link` element and use that instead.*